# application error during debugging

Tags: c#, android, xamarin-studio

Am new in Xamarian.While debugging a pop up window is coming with error that i mentioned below.i am not able to see anything related to API level in app properties.how do i fix this error?

```
 Target device (emulator-5554) has an API level of 10, but this application has a minimum

 API level of 19 set.

 minimum API level can be changed in the project properties on the Android Manifest tab.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start Emulator with API level 19, or set API level 10 in your AndroidManifext.xml. such as:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```